# hyperledger fabric - How to remove a chaincode on peer?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I installed two `chaincode` on a peer:

```
☁  basic-network [master] ⚡  ../../bin/peer chaincode list --installed
2018-06-25 10:37:44.825 CST [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2018-06-25 10:37:44.825 CST [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-06-25 10:37:44.825 CST [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 003 Sign: plaintext: 0A9C070A5C08031A0C08F8AAC1D90510...74616C6C6564636861696E636F646573
2018-06-25 10:37:44.825 CST [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 004 Sign: digest: 3F5F76846525A16930FC348CB24BC6D7C989EAF9D23E090D339C5D0B65E09D0E
Get installed chaincodes on peer:
Name: r_test_cc6, Version: 1.0, Path: chaincode_example02/go, Id: c7d2878644787e34a25b1e4e46703c7da301a830b68eba8e71ba7cadd2fbd480
Name: r_test_cc6, Version: 1.1, Path: github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02/go, Id: 42583a192be4d33bc2ddc85b3e061971667533019d431729bbac80f8844a00fe
2018-06-25 10:37:44.828 CST [main] main -> INFO 005 Exiting.....
```

I want to `remove` or `delete` the `chaincode` on a peer. How can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To remove a chaincode on a peer you need to:

- Kill the container that corresponds to the chaincode shim since a chaincode [runs inside a docker container](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chaincode4noah.html).
- Delete the chaincode from the file system of the peer under /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes

Comment: thanks. what if I start a peer node in my local machine, not in docker container?

Comment: Is there any docs about chaincode always runs in a docker container?

Comment: yeah... I edited the answer and provided a link. From the link:

"Chaincode is a program, written in Go, and eventually in other programming languages such as Java, that implements a prescribed interface. Chaincode runs in a secured Docker container "

Comment: Do these actions remove the chaincode from channel configuration/current information?

Comment: No, they don't.

Comment: I have removed container which is running my chaincode, though it's showing in chaincodes list.. I have created multiple versions also for chaincode. all versions are showing on chaincode list. Please help me how can i remove completely.

Comment: I have tried this but I try to reinstall the chaincode and I get: Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg chaincode with name 'mycc' already exists

Answer (score 3):

1) You can **upgrade** your chaincode and hit request to new chaincode.

adding to @yacovm 's answer -

2) You also need to delete docker image of the chaincode created :

> docker images
>
> docker rmi $(docker images chaincode_name -q)

If you want to remove multiple images as once ( assuming your chaincode image name starts with  "cc_") try :

> docker rmi $(docker images cc_* -q)

Answer (score 3):

For Fabric 2.x

1. Kill the chaincode container
2. Delete the chaincode from the file system of the peer under
   **/var/hyperledger/production/lifecycle/chaincodes**
3. Restart your **peer** container.

PS. After restarting the peer container all your chaincode containers will be restarted wait till all the containers are up.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the image.

docker image list (find the image ID e.g. Image ID 3baa6abf8ac8)

docker image rm -f 3baa6abf8ac8

Answer (score 1):

The other way of deleting the docker images in **Linux**

1. To delete all images

> docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)

2. To delete all containers including its volumes use,

> docker rm -vf $(docker ps -a -q)

**Note** *-f:* This command force-removes a running container.

Remember, you should remove all the containers before removing all the images from which those containers were created.

Answer (score 0):

#### Fabric 2.x - CCAAS

The following is applicable to **CC deployed as external service (CCAAS)**.

1. Spawn a shell on the peer(s) pod(or container). e.g. `kubectl exec -it peer0-org1-some-alphanumerics sh -n the-namespace`
2. check your installed chaincodes: `ls /var/hyperledger/production/lifecycle/chaincodes/`.
3. delete the cc you don't want: `rm /var/hyperledger/production/lifecycle/chaincodes/someunwantedcc-with-alphanumerics.tat.gz`
4. restart the pod(container).

> Note: There is also a copy of the cc *tgz* under the `/var/hyperledger/production/externalbuilder/builds/` folder which doesn't seem to block the process.

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop containers of the running chaincode by(dev-peer - change it with phrase that your own chaincode starts with):

```
docker ps -a --filter "name=dev-peer*" | xargs docker container stop
```

2. Remove images of that chaincode:

```
docker images -q "dev-peer*" | xargs docker rmi -f
```

3. Remove containers of that chaincode:

```
docker ps -a --filter "name=dev-peer*" | xargs docker rm
```

4. Remove chaincode files from each peer container:

```
docker exec -it <peer_container_name> sh
rm /var/hyperledger/production/lifecycle/chaincodes/*
exit
```

5. Restart docker images with Peer:

```
docker restart $(docker ps -a --filter "name=peer" -q)
```