# Can you kill a smart contract in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, ethereum

Can you delete hyperledger fabric smart contract like the kill function in ethereum?

Comment: See yacovm answer on how to remove  Chaincode from a peer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51018342/11352925

Answer (score 2):

To kill a chaincode(Smart contract) you need to follow following steps:

- Kill chaincode containers belonging to respective chaincode version, which you want to kill. You may kill containers using following command:-

  docker rm -f [Chaincode docker container's ids separated by space]
- Delete chaincode images, using following command:-

  docker rmi [Chaincode images ids]
- Delete the chaincode from the file system of each peer under /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes

> Right now this is the procedure to uninstall a chaincode, in future there will be stop and start command to stop and resume a smart contract respectively. You may checkout the same in official documentation:-

[Hyperledger fabric chaincode lifecycle](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/chaincode4noah.html#chaincode-lifecycle)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have added point to delete chaincode images too.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the containers and images for your smartcontract, but if you go to the peer container the foulder /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes is empty.

If you run hyperledger explorer you will see that the contract remains and if you want install again with same name obtains an error, so the question is where and how you can remove this link in hyperledger 2.3?