# How to completly remove chaincode from peers in Hyperledger

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

Till now when I upgrade the chaincode I just increment the version and sequence of the new chaincode package but I was wondering if there is a way to clean up old chaincode by deleting it so that the unwanted chaincode no longer uses up system resources.
[image: Hyperledger chaincode list]

Comment: Do you have permission and method to access the system where chaincode is installed? If your chaincode is generally configured and is running based on a docker container, artificially delete unused docker chaincode containers and images in the system.

Comment: I run it locally in a VM. I did delete all the chaincode images with `docker rmi` but they still appear in the chaincode option of Explorer.

Comment: If you have already cleaned up the images and containers, the system resources are not already being used. This information is the history of the chaincode recorded on the fabric.

Answer (score 0):

This is an open issue in the Hyperledger Fabric community and likely scheduled for a future release. There is a JIRA issue with BACKLOG status at this time: [FAB-5781](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-5781)

Meanwhile all you can do is follow the instructions in another [Stackoverflow comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51018342/5726546).

You basically remove the chaincode container and delete the chaincode files within the peer container.